# How to come back on parent Tab activity from its child Tab activity

Tags: android, tabs

How to come back on parent Tab activity from its child activity whenever click on that particular tab .(In case of TabGroupActivity)

Comment: Please update your question to match what you actually are asking for as discussed below. It increases the possibility of it being answered.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Or call activity..........

```
Intent cityIntent = new Intent(getParent(),
                    YourActivity.class);
            TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity) getParent();
            parentActivity
                    .startChildActivity("YourActivity", cityIntent);
```

Comment: I want to come back on parent tab activity by clicking on that particular tab, instead of back press.

Comment: I have 3 tabs .Tab1 ,Tab2,Tab3...Tab1 has 3 child Activity -> Child1 ,child2,child3...Now  i am  at child1 and i want to go back on Tab1 home activity by clicking on Tab1 instead of back press.